# Como deixar o meu Button inabilitado mas aparecendo a imagem?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Alguém sabe se tem alguma opção de eu deixar meu Button inabilitado mas aparecendo a imagem do  Button?

Como fica se eu desabilito o Button.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código XAML do Button.

```
<Button x:Name="BtnCalc" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="773,206,-172,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Click="BtnCalc_Click" Height="85"
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/calculador.png"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim:

Coloque um `<Button.Content>` dentro um `<StackPanel>` e por fim um `<Image>`, vai resolver esse problema

```
<Button Name="BtnCalc"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
        Margin="53,62,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="266" Height="136" Click="BtnCalc_Click_1">
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="images/1.jpg"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Esses é um exemplo adeque ao seu com as medidas da imagem.